# how to move Text Field above my toolbar which is added above key board

Tags: ios

I have added a toolbar with button to dismiss the keyboard above the keyboard and am using notifications to move text field but how to consider the height of toolbar while scrollingRect

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scroll.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scroll scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance variable for the height of the keyboard accessory view (e.g. `float accessoryViewHeight`), and set it when the accessory view is created.  Then, in the code you posted, use the `kbSize + the accessoryViewHeight` in place of `kbSize.height.`

Example:

```
...
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
float totalKBHeight = kbSize.height + accessoryViewHeight;

UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, totalKBHeight, 0.0);
...
aRect.size.height -= totalKBHeight;
```

Comment: In the first place its not moving up because i think the textview is  slightly above the keyboard but its covered my toolbar which is above the keyboard